# ApplyTransformListener.ApplyResult in Marklogic Java Client Api?

Tags: marklogic, java

It seems the ApplyTransformListener method `withApplyResult` has two values(i.e.`REPLACE` AND `IGNORE`) , As said in the [documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/datamovement/ApplyTransformListener.html) the defintion is like  this `Whether to REPLACE each document with the result of the transform, or run the transform with each document as input, but IGNORE the result.`

My Code, what it actually do is it will get the content from marklogic db and apply the transform module . Below i mentioned `ApplyTransformListener` snippet:

```
 ServerTransform transform = new ServerTransform("rest");
            ApplyTransformListener transformListener = new ApplyTransformListener()
              .withTransform(transform)
              .withApplyResult(ApplyResult.REPLACE)
```

My transform module(i.e.`rest`) is like this

```
function patt(context, params, content)
{ 
  var transformed = {};
  transformed.Update= {"New" : "Element"};
  transformed.Original= content;
  xdmp.nodeReplace(content, transformed);
};
exports.transform = patt;
```

By, using above code the transform module will get the content and apply `xdmp.nodeReplace(content, transformed)`.

My question :

Even i applied `IGNORE` in the `applyresult` like this

```
ServerTransform transform = new ServerTransform("rest");
                ApplyTransformListener transformListener = new ApplyTransformListener()
                  .withTransform(transform)
                  .withApplyResult(ApplyResult.IGNORE)
```

Still it is applying the changes of Transform module. Why is it ?

It have to IGNORE the results of Transform module right(i.e.the original data in the document should not be changed right) ?

Correct me if i am wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you call `xdmp.nodeReplace` you are changing the document, and we don't prevent you from doing that.  The `IGNORE` option is for scenarios like these where you want to control your own modifications, perhaps even to other documents.

With `REPLACE` your transform function would return the new document you want to replace your document comments.  See this [example from the guide](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/data-movement#id_22702).

Answer (score 1):

IGNORE is not equivalent to a dry run. Rather, `withApplyResult` controls whether or MarkLogic automatically replaces the original content with the content returned by your transform function, or discards (ignores) the content returned by your transform function; any changes your transform function applies to the database still "stick" when you use IGNORE.